# NavHostFragment and ViewPager2 doesn't work at the same time

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-viewpager2

I have an app, that has a few fragments in it. I'm using `ViewPager 2` to swipe between them.

Lately I've added `Navigation component` to make a way to get into one specific fragment that is not avilable for user just by swipe.

I've found out, that whever I place `FragmentContainerView` over the `ViewPager2` in my `MainActivity` layout, I can go to this unvailable fragment, but I can't swipe. Same thing whener I switch `FragmentContainerView` with `ViewPager2`. Is there any way to make them both work at the same time?

Here's my layout

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can work together but not like this, at least not for what you want.

`Navigation component` is made to handle traveling **between** destinations. `ViewPager2` is a widget to be used **in** a destination, not for traveling between them.

For what you are describing you will need to have `FragmentA` that will contain `ViewPager2` where all of the swiping will take place and handling of fragments (let's say `Fragment1`, `Fragment2`, `Fragment3`) in the `ViewPager2`.

Those fragments will have nothing to do with the `Navigation component`.

`Navigation component` will come to play when you will want to go from `FragmentA` to `FragmentB`.

Comment: Thank you for such explanation. Appreciate it.